# How can I make the Outlook 2007 inbox look like this again?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Came back from vacation, work Outlook was screwed up. The inbox looked like this, with subject, sender, time, etc. all in a row:

[image]

How can I make the inbox look like the below screenshot again, with the messages in a more compact type of view (horizontally stacked, if you will)?

[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what it looks like now, and provide some additional comments as to what you're looking to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is Compact View. [To guarantee it displays in Compact View](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f57/outlook-keeps-changing-to-one-line-message-view-302550.html):

> uncheck "Use compact layout in widths smaller than x characters" then set it to Always use compact layout in the Other Settings... dialog box from the Customize View... options.

[You can customize what is on the top or bottom line by](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f57/outlook-keeps-changing-to-one-line-message-view-302550.html)

> View menu, then Current View, and then Customize Current View (note that you could create a new view for this setting if you wanted)

Answer (score 3):

Go to View, then Reading Pane and then choose RIGHT.

Comment: No, that's not it, sorry. I meant the message list.

Comment: That would have been a great detail to add to the original question. Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/372685/edit) your question so it is understandable to help others if they have the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
"View Settings"
"Other Settings" 
First down to:
 "AutoPreview" 
 Select "No AutoPreview"
Then down to:
 "Reading Pane"
 Select "Right"
Then down to:
 "Other Options"
 Select "Always Use compact layout"
Click OK,
Then OK again.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. I know you are new to this site, but wanted to make you aware you are posting an answer to a 3-year old question that has an excepted answer already. There is nothing wrong with doing so, just realize it may not be responded to or accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the part of the frame between the inbox and the reading area, then move it to the left, to where it was before.